# TypeError: psd() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Fc'

Tags: python, psd

While i executing this code it show's an error, I'm using `matplotlib.mlab` `psd`

here's the code,

```
from matplotlib.mlab import psd
from rtlsdr import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sdr = RtlSdr()

# configure device
sdr.sample_rate = 2.4e6
p = sdr.center_freq = 95e6
sdr.gain = 'auto'
arr_db = []
arr_fq = []

def plot_graph():
    print(len(arr_db))
    print(len(arr_fq))
    xlabel('Frequency (MHz)')
    ylabel('Relative power (dB)')
    #plt.plot(arr_db, arr_fq, color='blue')
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.5)
    plt.clf()

while True:   
    # use matplotlib to estimate and plot the PSD
    samples = sdr.read_samples(256*1024)
    a = psd(samples.real, NFFT=1024, Fs=sdr.sample_rate/1e6, Fc=p/1e6)
    p+= 1000000
    for i in range(513):
        b = a[0][i]
        c = a[1][i]
        arr_db.append(b)
        arr_fq.append(c)
    plot_graph()
    
sdr.close()
```

And the error showing like this,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Ismail\rtl_sdr\sample.py", line 27, in <module>
    a = psd(samples.real, NFFT=1024, Fs=sdr.sample_rate/1e6, Fc=p/1e6)
TypeError: psd() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Fc'
Found Rafael Micro R820T/2 tuner
```

can anyone help

Comment: From https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.psd, it doesn't seem as if ```psd``` takes any ```Fc``` arguments.

Comment: @ewokx Ok, fine...now I edited my question and added the full code now can you tell me how to fix this error

Comment: There is [matplotlib.mlab.psd()](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/d6dd1b79142e4e2483244c25ff1e3ddb664722d3/lib/matplotlib/mlab.py#L535) which does not have `Fc` and also [matplotlib.pyplot.psd()](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/d6dd1b79142e4e2483244c25ff1e3ddb664722d3/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L2802) which has. Here are the docs https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.psd and https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.psd.html

Answer (score 0):

You've imported the wrong `psd` function.

You're looking for [`matplotlib.pyplot.psd`](http://matplotlib.org/3.7.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.psd.html#matplotlib.pyplot.psd); you have [`matplotlib.mlab.psd`](http://matplotlib.org/3.7.1/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.psd), which has a different signature.

Change your import to

```
-from matplotlib.mlab import psd
+from matplotlib.pyplot import psd
```

or just use `plt.psd` since you have `pyplot` imported as `plt`.